# How do I continue playing a video's audio track after a screen lock in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, locking, ios5, screen, mpmovieplayercontroller

iOS5 pushes your app to the background when the screen is locked.

In my UIBackgroundModes in the plist file, I can set audio, location and voip to continue in the background.

How about video? I'm using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a video file but I do not want the video to pause on a screen lock. It's fine if the user cannot see the video, but I still want the audio to continue playing.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No solution to this problem yet. The only one that might work is:

Have a separate audio and video track that start simultaneously. Continue audio on screen lock and on screen unlock, jump the video to the audio file's progress.

Answer (score 1):

Disable using the app-audio-session by adding the following to your MPMoviePlayerController initialization (assuming your instance of that class is called player);

```
player.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

Comment: Hi Till, thanks for the response. I tried what you said, with and without background audio enabled in my plist, and it didn't work. The device won't lock as long as the video is playing but as soon as I lock it myself, the video and it's associated audio stop playing.